# To find the probability?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, probability, statistics

The mass of the earth is 5.975 X 10^27 g of average atomic weight 30.00 g. The fraction (by weight) of the earth that is gold has been estimated  to be 3 X 10^-9. The atomic weight of gold is about 197 g. If you were to pick a gram of soil (or rock), what is the probability that it would be at least 90% gold?

Comment: On the assumption that gold is dispersed evenly, the probability is effectively zero. But that assumption is false - the deposition of gold is highly uneven throughout the earth's crust and you can't use simple statistics based on the numbers given (or rather, you could, but it would be completely wrong to do so).

Answer (score 3):

In general if you have m out of n atoms *on average* of a certain composition, then if you take a sample of size N, you can approximate the distribution of atoms with a binomial distribution with mean

$$mean = N \frac{m}{n}$$

and standard deviation

$$std = \sqrt{N\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)}$$

This is on the assumption that the atoms are uniformly distributed. This assumption is false in the case of gold in the earth's crust - there are processes that have been at work for millions of years that cause gold to aggregate into ore deposits: hence the gold rush...

In your case, you could compute the average number of atoms in one gram as about 1/30th of a mole, so

$$N = \frac{N_A}{30} = 2 \cdot 10^{22}$$

When the fraction of gold atoms is 3 in $10^{-9}$ by weight, it is about $\frac{30}{197}\cdot 3\cdot 10^{-9}=4.6\cdot 10^{-10} : 1$ atoms.

Plugging these values for $N$ and $\frac{m}{n}$ into the above, we get

$$mean = 3\cdot 10^{22} * 4.6 \cdot 10^{-10} =14\cdot 10^{13} atoms/gram$$

with a standard deviation of

$$std = \sqrt{2\cdot^{22} \cdot\ 4.6 \cdot 10^{-10}}\approx3\cdot 10^6$$

To get to 90% gold, you would need $$\frac{0.9*2\cdot 10^{22} - 14 \cdot 10^{13}}{3\cdot 10^{6}} $$ standard deviations.

As I mentioned in my comment, that's "effectively zero" unless the Gaussian assumption of random variables is incorrect.

Comment: i am actually facing problem with "atleast 90%" part! i think i should have soe continuous probability distribution so that i can integrate for more than 90%

Comment: @seeking_infinity the "continuous probability distribution" you are looking for is the tail of the cumulative normal distribution at approximately $10^{14}$ standard deviations. I don't think that is computable. But if it was, multiplying that number by the number of "1 gram particles" on earth, and again by the number of seconds that the earth is old (pick up and evaluate one particle per second), and you still end up with "zero". Yet nuggets exist because the physics of formation of the earth allows gold atoms to aggregate.